# Want to call a public method with all data members in another public method from same public class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, methods

Want to call a public method with all data members  in another public method from same public class.

I am not understanding why datamembers are not getting access of method "testAddKOL" as I am calling a whole method by creating an object of same class.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "datatest")
public void testAddKOL(Map data) throws Exception {

    String kolname = (String) data.get("kolname");
    String kolemail = (String) data.get("kolemail");

    mouseOver(mykol.mousehoverKOLlist);
    waitforelementpresent(mykol.addicon);
    click(mykol.addicon);

}

@Test(dataProvider = "datatest")
public void addkoltoList(Map data) throws Exception {

    MyKOL add = new MyKOL();
    add.testAddKOL(data); // calling a method by creating the object

    waitforelementpresent(mykol.mousehoverKOLlist);

    mouseOver(mykol.mousehoverKOLlist);

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to call method, because my whole use of that method is in another method,

Comment: You can make two tests dependent in `testng`

Answer (score 0):

Instead the creating class object & calling the method:

`MyKOL add = new MyKOL();
 add.testAddKOL(data);`

Just call the method:

`testAddKOL(data);`